# Reduice time computation using parallel package in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, parallel-processing, vectorization

I searched but I couldn't find a similar question, so Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate question. I am trying to Generate a data frame from within a for loop in R.

what I want to do is to use  the package parallel to compute a function for `N=10^9` differents values.

So this is the code I did:

1- To generate sample of data, and all the parameters of the model  :

```
Data=data.frame(C=rnorm(10,150,12),K=rnorm(10,95,7),S=rnorm(10,125,9.5),T=rnorm(10,25,5))
round(Data, digits = 0)
para_h<-c(0.001,0.002,0.0000154,0.00052,-0.68)
```

2- The function that I use :

```
FC_Q<-function(x,para_h,Data){
  T=Data$T; S=Data$S; K=Data$K; r=0.05/250
  w=para_h[1];b=para_h[2];a=para_h[3];  c= para_h[4];  neta=para_h[5]

  nu=(1/(neta^2))*(((1-2*neta)^(1/2))-1)
  u=1i*x ; Z=length(S)

  FC_Q <- rep(NA, Z)
  for (i in 1:Z){
    A_Q=0 ; B_Q=0
    steps<-round(T[i]*250,0)  
    for (j in 1:steps){
      A_Q= A_Q+ r*u + w*B_Q-(1/2)*log(1-2*a*(neta^4)*B_Q)
      B_Q= b*B_Q+u*nu+ (1/neta^2)*(1-sqrt((1-2*a*(neta^4)*B_Q)*( 1- 2*c*B_Q - 2*u*neta)))
    }
    FC_Q[i]= exp(log(S[i])*u + A_Q + B_Q*(0.0012))*exp(-r*T[i])
  }
  return(FC_Q)
}
```

The problem I have is due to the dimensions of computation `N=10^9`  it takes 1 hours on my computer.

This is the code I used to do the cumputation with loops  `for`.

```
N=10^9 ; alpha=2 ; delta= 0.25; lambda=(2*pi)/(N*delta); r=0.05/250

Res=c()
for (i in 1:N){
  phi= ((FC_Q(((delta*(i-1))-(alpha+1)*1i),para_h,Data))/(alpha^2+alpha-(delta*(i-1))^2+1i*(2*alpha+1)*(delta*(i-1))))*delta*exp(1i*(delta*(i-1))*b)
  Res=rbind(Res,phi)
}
```

This code take a lot of hours, What I want to use is some thing like :

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
result <- clusterApply(cl,1:10^9,FC_Q)
values <- do.call(rbind,result)
stopCluster(cl)
```

is it possible to reduce the execution time using package parallel and if so, please suggest me a solution. I known, I´m using a lot of bad things for R, but I could not figure out a better solution.

Any correction and suggestion to improve this process! please feel free to share your extant code in R.

Thanks.

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit open-ended.
If your goal is to run code on multiple cores / processors, one of the simplest solutions is to use mclapply from the parallel package. Since it uses forking, it will not work out-of-the-box on Windows machine.

To use it:

```
num_cores <- 12
res <- mclapply(1:N, function(i) ((FC_Q(((delta*(i-1))-(alpha+1)*1i),para_h,Data))/(alpha^2+alpha-(delta*(i-1))^2+1i*(2*alpha+1)*(delta*(i-1))))*delta*exp(1i*(delta*(i-1))*b), 
                mc.cores = num_cores)
```

mclapply returns a list.